# Intel SSD X25-M, Smart Attributes, Lifetime writes

Tags: windows-7, ssd

What are others Intel SSD Smart Attributes reporting?  I'm curious what others have for error counts and for those that have written many TB of data due to the limited write lifetime of SSD (see quote).  If you near the ~35TB of lifetime writes hopefully you would see a error rate increase and a windows based smart hard drive error in win7?

My X-25M G2 80GB on day 3 is reporting (from the Intel SSD toolbox):

*spin up (Id 3), start/stop (Id 4), re-allocated sectors(Id 5), avb reserved space(Id E8), Media wearout indicator(E9), end to end error detection count (B8) **all at zero**.*

*then 56 hrs power on, power cycle count 15, unsafe shutdown count 15, and host writes* 73.31 GB.

> **Minimum Useful Life:** 
>  **X25-M & X18-M**: [MLC]  1.2M hours MTBF;
>   5 years - 35TB written, up to 20GB/day for 5 years
>   **X25-E** [SLC] 2.0 M Hrs MTBF; 3 years - 1PB random writes for 32GB drive, 2PB for 64GB drive
>   [Intel SSD Training, Rev 2.ppt]

Comment: Do you agree with the report where it says it's been power-cycled 15 times in the last 56 hours?

Comment: that is about right, installed windows 7 fresh twice onto it and it hangs after exiting windows with the fans kicked to high speed.

Comment: Old, but throwing this out there...we often see brand new X25-Ms with gigs of host writes and double-digit unsafe shutdowns.  I wonder what they do at the factory...

Comment: Downvoting because this site is not about compiling lists like this. This question should be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The results for my X25-M G2 80GB drive are:

648 power-on hours, 97 power cycles, 16 unsafe shutdowns, and 256.16GB host writes. All other SMART attributes are 0 (as I'd hope).

Comment: thanks, I feel safer with Intel's Smart Attributes in contrast to the somewhat confidential Smart attributes from Seagate/WD. For example, my ST3500320AS reports 13785 power on hrs with 225m read errors but no reallocated sectors.

Comment: Downvoting because this site is not about compiling lists like this. This question should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

The results for my X25-M G2 80 GB drive are:

- Power on hours: 28900,
- Power cycle count: 2198,
- Unsafe shutdown count: 919,
- Media Wearout Indicator: 91 (Normalized),
- Host writes: 5200.09 GB.

(From Intel Solid-State Drive Toolbox v3.5.11.)

I'm in the process of replacing this SSD and was curious about its wear-level. 
It's been running reliably in an Ubuntu server for a few years.

Comment: Downvoting because this site is not about compiling lists like this. This question should be closed.